# Linq and Lambda Expressions with postgreSQL database

Tags: c#, sql, linq, postgresql, lambda

Is it possible to use Lambda Expressions to query a PostgreSQL database in C#?

I've tried with ODBC and with Npgsql, but haven't found a way to do so yet.

What I would like to do is something similar to what I can do with a mongo database using lambda expressions with linq:

```
MongoCollection<BsonDocument> collection = 
                    database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(s);
IEnumerable<string> colNames = 
                    collection.AsQueryable().Skip(6).First().Select(e => e.Name);
```

Which allows me to do a lot in very few lines.

Comment: You may be able to use [this](http://www.nuget.org/packages/linq2db.PostgreSQL/1.0.2) and there looks to be docs and example for it [here](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db)

Comment: seems like that is the same as creating an entity model, which limits me to known databases, I would like to be able to manipulate an unknown database. In other words I want to be able to type in different server addresses and not have to add code for each server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No other way besides creating an entity model.